How to send a json file using a telegram bot?
I am getting this error when using sendDocument:
GrammyError: Call to 'sendDocument' failed! (400: Bad Request: invalid file HTTP URL specified: Wrong port number specified in the URL)

Code:
          const file = await fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "files", "history_988386602_2.json"), "utf8")
          const document = new InputFile(file)

          await Bot.api.sendDocument(msg.chatId, document)


I wonder if these are related or helpful: NTBA_FIX_350 or sendDocument issue or DeprecationWarning
